# Shifting cells to up in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with some messy data.

**I have following dataframe in pandas**

| Name | Age | Sex | Salary | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 32 | Nan | NaN | NaN |
| Nan | Male | 4000 | Single | NaN |
| May | 20 | Female | 5000 | Married |
| teresa | 45 |  |  |  |

**Desired output:**

```
   Name   Age     Sex Salary  Status
0  John   32    Male   4000  Single
1   May   20  Female   5000  Married
2  teresa 45
```

So Does anyone know how to do it with Pandas?

Comment: Maybe you should fix your file. Can you update a sample of your csv file, please?

Comment: @TõnisPiip this is the data that i have and yes 4000 is under sex and Single under "Salary". Yes it's ok to remove the second row i just want to move the values to the up

Comment: @TõnisPiip - That is the question. What can you do if you have a corrupted import with additional *nan* values that messed up your columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit of numpy magic to drop the NaNs and reshape the underlying array:

```
a = df.replace({'Nan': float('nan')}).values.flatten()
pd.DataFrame(a[~pd.isna(a)].reshape(-1, len(df.columns)),
             columns=df.columns)
```

output:

```
   Name Age     Sex Salary   Status
0  John  32    Male   4000   Single
1   May  20  Female   5000  Married
```

Comment: I already tried this solution and i got this error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2234 into shape (5)`

Comment: Then please provide an example for which it doesn't work

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich can you elaborate on the bug? regarding the NaNs positions, from the example it seems that they are shifted left to right then top to bottom, if there is another logic then this is an impossible problem to solve

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich - This solution works without an error and gives the correct result (and should work for dataframes with a similar structur). Where did you spot a bug? Your solution still gives a different result for the provided example.

Comment: @Prestige can you provide the dataset? This might mean that you do not have all the data, in which case you could pad the values at the end with NaNs to get a shape that is a multiple of `len(df.column)`, but this might simply means that there are arbitrary missing values with the dataset in which case what you ask is impossible to achieve without ambiguity

Comment: @mozway the error come from rows with empty values in some columns

Comment: @mozway yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try `groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby(df['Name'].notna().cumsum()).apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda x: next(iter(x.dropna()), np.nan))).reset_index(drop=True)
   Name Age     Sex  Salary   Status
0  John  32    4000  Single      NaN
1   May  20  Female    5000  Married
>>>
```

Comment: This does not yield the expected output, you are losing values in the process ;)